# 3D Direct Convolution Implementation in C

Tags: performance, c, memory-management, simd

For my project, I've written a naive C implementation of Direct3D convolution with periodic padding on the input. Unfortunately, since I'm new to C, the performance isn't so good.

By convention, all the matrices (image, kernel, result) are stored in column-major fashion. This is why I loop through them in such way so they are closer in memory. As I heard this would help.

I know the implementation is very naive. But since it's written in C, I was hoping the performance would be good, but instead it's a little disappointing. I tested it with image of size \$100^3\$ and kernel of size \$10^3\$ which totals ~1GFLOPS if you only count the multiplication and addition. This took ~7s which I believe is way below the capability of a typical CPU.

Could the performance be optimized in this routine?
I'm open to anything that could help, with just a few things if you could consider:

1. The problem I'm working on can be big. Image's size can be 200 by 200 by 200 whilst the kernel's size can be 50 by 50 by 50 or even larger. I understand that one way of optimizing this is by converting this problem into a matrix multiplication problem and use the blas GEMM routine, but I'm afraid memory could not hold such a big matrix
2. Due to the nature of the problem I would prefer direct convolution instead of FFTConvolve, since my model is developed with direct convolution in mind. My impression of FFTconvolve is that it gives slightly different result than direct convolve, especially for rapidly changing image. A discrepancy I'm trying to avoid.
   That said, I'm in no way an expert in this. so if you have a great implementation based on FFTconvolve and / or my impression on FFTconvolve is totally biased, I would really appreciate if you could help me out.
3. The input images are assumed to be periodic, so periodic padding is necessary
4. I understand that utilizing blas / SIMD or other lower level ways would definitely help a lot here. but since I'm a newbie here I don't really know where to start. I would really appreciate if you help pointing me to the right direction if you have experience in these libraries,

```
int mod(int a, int b)
{
    // calculate mod to get the correct index with periodic padding
    int r = a % b;
    return r < 0 ? r + b : r;
}
void convolve3D(const double *image, const double *kernel, const int imageDimX, const int imageDimY, const int imageDimZ, const int kernelDimX, const int kernelDimY, const int kernelDimZ, double *result)
{
    int imageSize = imageDimX * imageDimY * imageDimZ;
    int kernelSize = kernelDimX * kernelDimY * kernelDimZ;

    int i, j, k, l, m, n;
    int kernelCenterX = (kernelDimX - 1) / 2;
    int kernelCenterY = (kernelDimY - 1) / 2;
    int kernelCenterZ = (kernelDimZ - 1) / 2;
    int xShift,yShift,zShift;
    int outIndex, outI, outJ, outK;
    int imageIndex = 0, kernelIndex = 0;
    
    // Loop through each voxel
    for (k = 0; k < imageDimZ; k++){
        for ( j = 0; j < imageDimY; j++) {
            for ( i = 0; i < imageDimX; i++) {
                kernelIndex = 0;
                // for each voxel, loop through each kernel coefficient
                for (n = 0; n < kernelDimZ; n++){
                    for ( m = 0; m < kernelDimY; m++) {
                        for ( l = 0; l < kernelDimX; l++) {
                            // find the index of the corresponding voxel in the output image
                            xShift = l - kernelCenterX;
                            yShift = m - kernelCenterY;
                            zShift = n - kernelCenterZ;

                            outI = mod ((i - xShift), imageDimX);
                            outJ = mod ((j - yShift), imageDimY);
                            outK = mod ((k - zShift), imageDimZ);
                            
                            outIndex = outK * imageDimX * imageDimY + outJ * imageDimX + outI;

                            // calculate and add
                            result[outIndex] += kernel[kernelIndex]* image[imageIndex];
                            kernelIndex++;
                        }
                    }
                } 
                imageIndex ++;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: [as discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62603086/optimization-of-3d-direct-convolution-implementation-in-c#comment110709682_62603086) on the Stack Overflow version of this question, `%` is very slow with divisors that aren't compile-time constants.  Replacing that with a conditional add (assuming it can't wrap more than once) sped up the whole thing by 20%.  (Compiling with `-O3` with an unknown compiler on unknown hardware, presumably not `-march=native` or `-ffast-math`.)

Comment: Does this compile? `kernelIndex` is declared, and later incremented, but never used anywhere. `stencil` and `stencilIndex` is only referenced, never declared or defined. Are they supposed to be `kernel` and `kernelIndex`? Requests for reviews of [broken code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650/9683) are off-topic here.

Comment: @scottbb ah, yes, I changed it from stencil to kernel when copying my code, and missed some... I have corrected the typo

Comment: Some "little"...  `for (n = 0, zShift = - kernelCenterZ; n < kernelDimZ; n++, zShift++){` and the next 2 loops also. You can remove the 3 substractions in the inner body. They were calculated too often.

Comment: `outK` and `outJ` don't need to be allways recalculated in the inner loop.

Comment: @Holger Yes!  Thanks a lot for pointing those out! with those adjustment, it is now 50% faster!

Answer (score 2):

## Use FFTs

With large kernel sizes, it will certainly be faster to use FFTs, as this will be a \$O(N \log N)\$ solution, where \$N\$ is the number of voxels in the image, whereas your solution is \$O(N M)\$, where \$M\$ is the number of number of voxels in the kernel. The direct convolution has a smaller constant factor, but even for \$100^3\$ voxel images and \$10^3\$ voxel kernels, FFT will most likely already be faster.

> My impression of FFTconvolve is that it gives slightly different result than direct convolve,

Correct, as it does a different number of operations, and a computer's floating point numbers have finite precision, so rounding errors will accumulate differently. But even direct convolution has rounding errors, and given that you are doing more operations in direct convolution, not less, it might even be that convolving using FFTs is slightly more accurate.

> especially for rapidly changing image.

I assume you mean if there are very high frequency components in the image? The FFT algorithm can handle those just fine, but finite floating point precision might always introduce small errors, and they might be smaller or larger depending on the implementation of the algorithm. I would try out convolving a "rapidly changing image" with a 1x1 unity kernel using FFTs, and then looking at the difference before and after the convolution to get an estimate of the error introduced by the FFTs.

There are several libraries that can do FFTs for you, a very good one is [FFTW](https://www.fftw.org/). It also makes use of SIMD instructions. You still have to implement the convolution step yourself, but it's just element-wise multiplication of the transformed image and kernel, and compilers can vectorize such a simple `for`-loop for you as well.

> The input images are assumed to be periodic, so periodic padding is necessary

The Fourier transform already assumes periodic boundary conditions, so nothing special has to be done to handle periodic input images.

## Avoid modulo operations

As Peter Cordes already mentioned, `%` is very slow if the divisor is not a compile-time constant. There are several ways to avoid it:

1. Ensure the dimensions of the image are powers of two. This way you can use a bitwise-AND (`&`) instead to replace the modulo operation.
2. Split each of the image dimension loops in three regions: from `0` to `kernelDim / 2` where the kernel wraps, from `kernelDim / 2` to `imageDim - kernelDim / 2` where the kernel is guaranteed not to wrap, and one for the remaining bit where the kernel once more wraps. In the region where the kernel does not wrap, you can then avoid using `%`.
3. Make use of the fact that `outI`, `outJ` and `outK` only get decremented by `1` at a time. An `if`-statement to check if they must be wrapped might then be faster:

   ```
   for (outK = (k + kernelCenterZ) % imageDimZ, n = 0; n < kernelDimZ; n++) {
     for (...) {
       for (...) {
           ...
       }
     }

     outK--;
     if (outK < 0)
         outK += imageDimZ;
   }
   ```

   On modern CPUs with branch predictors, this might be almost free.

## Make use of special properties of the convolution kernel

If you know that the convolution kernel has some properties, such as symmetries around one or more axes, or if it is [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter), you can change your algorithm to take advantage of those properties and potentially be much more efficient.